# ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)

Tags: ldap

I am configuring my LDAP for roaming profiles using autofs, but when I run this command "ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -W -f automount.ldif" I end up on to an error "ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)
    additional info: invalid DN" I have googled lots of forums but still didn't find the solution, hopping I might find it here.

Comment: Please provide more information about your LDAP and the LDIF.

Comment: If you're on Mac make sure you don't have any `&quot;` in your build.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case it was a `seeAlso` attribute that was containing a timestamp instead of a DN.

If you would provide an example `automount.ldif` I could better assist you.